# Passing a dataset parameter in a data mapping acitivity in a data flow in Azure Data factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a parametrized dataset, that I used for a copy data activty and it worked fine.
I am trying to replicate that using a mapping dataflow but I cant find where to input the value for the dataset parameter...

Answer (score 2):

To clarify Joel's answer - you cannot assign parameter values to a Dataset from within the Data Flow settings. It is done from the Pipeline that executes the Data Flow. This means that you may get an error message if you attempt to 'Test connection' for a parameterised dataset.

Answer (score 0):

Parameterized Data Sets work exactly the same way in a Data Flow activity. If a Data Set used in the Data Flow has parameters, they will have configuration points on the Settings tab:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I landed here as I was having the same issue. I managed to work out the following.

At the top of the design panel you have an option for "Data Flow Debug". Turn that on. And having done so, you'll then be prompted for "Debug Settings" (which you can edit as required using the option that appears next to the "Data Flow Debug"). Here's a little screen-snip of the relevant stuff:

[image: Data Flow Screen-Snip]